# Rails support gem/engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to add a customer support function to an existing Rails 3 app. I want to enable the users to submit a support ticket and answer back and fourth until the issue is resolved. I am currently using Zendesk.

Does anyone have any knowledge of something I can use? Or should I just develop it myself?

Regards,

Jacob

Comment: What did you go with in the end? Did you custom build or did you find a gem?

Comment: I'm likewise curious about this.  Appears that no one has really put up any solutions to date.  We're wanting to replace Zendesk for all of our apps at the moment as it is just not making valid proposition for the cost.

Answer (score 0):

So you essentially want to be able to create a system to manage issues? Checkout [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/). It has the ability to [manage issues](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/issues). However, I'm pretty sure that the way it looks isn't the way you want yours to look.

You can lift the generic code from Redmine and apply it to your app. I doubt you'll find a gem that does all the magic for you the way you want it to look and act, so you'll need to do programming.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this. I saw it listed on [Open Source Help Desk List](http://www.opensourcehelpdesklist.com/) where both Redmine and Big Help are mentioned. I am also looking for a help desk gem and stumbled upon your question here.

[Big Help: A help desk portal built with Ruby on Rails](https://github.com/bigfolio/big-help)